# Analytic Accounts in StockPicking Model

Tags: odoo-16

I want to add analytic account field to stock.move Model in Odoo 16, in previous version of Odoo this was done by adding the following line:

```
analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one(related='purchase_line_id.account_analytic_id', store=True, string="Shipment No")
```

How can I do the same in Odoo 16, I prefer to follow the standard way Odoo 16 handles Analytic Accounts, i.e. use the domain of Analytic Plans to specify if the Analytic account is mandatory, optional or unavailable.

Thanks

Ameen

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this OCA addon](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/16.0/stock_analytic/), the addon adds Analytic Distribution field in stock move to be able to get analytic information when generating the journal items.